# can "way to do something" & "way of doing something" be used interchangeably

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In the [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/way_1?q=way)

> **way to do something** 
>  That's not the right way to hold a
>   pair of scissors. 
>  (informal, disapproving) That's no way to speak
>   to your mother! 
>  **way of doing something** 
>  I'm
>   not happy with this way of working.

I am not sure if "**way to do something**" & "**way of doing something**" can be used interchangeably?

Can I say:

I'm not happy with this way to work.

&

That's not the right way of holding a pair of scissors.

Comment: *"I'm not happy with this way to work."* - That doesn't sound right. "...this way of working" would be OK. The scissors example is fine with "of holding" or "to hold".

Answer (score 2):

I think they are somewhat different in concept.

> **way to do something**

*way **to do** something* refers to specific actions (in these examples holding scissors and speaking).

> That's not the right **way to hold** a pair of scissors.
>   That's no **way to speak** to your mother!

And

> **way of doing something**

*way of doing something* refers to style or methods.

> I'm not happy with **your way of doing** things.

Comment: If "way of..." refers to style or method, then doesn't "That's not the right way of holding a pair of scissors" refer to my personal cutting style?

Comment: @nnnnnn it refers to the way you grip the scissors, which influences but is not the same as how you cut.